# Apache Spark circuit breaker

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Using Apache Spark 1.6.2 in Hadoop YARN cluster.

Some (simple) queries can consume lot of resources, I see our developers running `SELECT * FROM DB` against a 1To file! Hence, it takes a long time and "block" all YARN resources for a moment (and crash most of the time after a few hours ...).

I am wondering if it's possible to limit time / resources consumed by Spark running in a YARN cluster:

- limit time duration
- limit shuffle (cache) disk space
- limit CPU time per query (or per user)

*(Not sure if "circuit breaker" is a good term, I took it from elasticsearch)*

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, but in general:

- Use scheduler queues to ensure optimal allocation between different users in multiuser environment. Proper capacity configuration should be enough to get a pretty good control.
- Use preemption to ensure that single application going out of hand doesn't block a single queue (but be careful if you consider cluster mode).
- Temporary space is trickier as YARN doesn't consider disk to be a resource, but standard OS quotas should work here.

Comment: Thanks you, yes we configure YARN queue already, now I think the problem is more on Spark itself, users cant cancel long query and are blocked by the fair scheduler.